# Recording jmeter script (website)?

Tags: jmeter

I was trying to record a shopping site using jmeter.

My flow is : Launch -> search -> view product -> add to cart .

When i am running this recording in my add to cart request - page is showing cart empty!!.

Kindly tell me how to proceed to get the item in the cart visible.

Comment: Did every other request record fine? Describe the procedure you followed for recording.What is your JMeter version?

Comment: version - 2.13 , first i recorded the main page of the site , 2 searched for a product say books , 3 selected 1 book , 4 added it to cart which showed 1 item added in cart ...when i run the flow in view result tree ..in 4th request cart is showing empty.....

Comment: Do you have add the HTTP Cookie Manager ? Please giver more details about your test.

Comment: yes i have added cookie and cache manager .. why is this  happening? in sampler result ; response code is 302 and page shows cart empty , while when i was recording the cart was having the item i added.

Comment: I completed the script.....Thank u to all :)